# Bluetooth my GPS signal to windows 10 tablet using QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps

Could anyone tell me how they pair their mobile phone gps to a (windows 10) tablet that can be picked up by qgis live tracking? I have tried a few apps which i believe is broadcasting the gps to my tablet (checking against google maps) but qgis is not picking up the gps information.

Comment: what bluetooth device are you using? is the COM port set? https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html

Comment: Thank you. The COM port was not set up properly. I posted my fix in another comment below

Answer (score 2):

I successfully used extGPS apps to perform this tricks.
the steps are:

- download extGPS from internet as it's not available from store... : http://downloadapk.net/ExtGPS.html
- Copy the .APK file on your mobile phone
- Install it by simply click on it from your phone
- connect your tablet to your phone by bluetooth
- launch the extGPS app on your phone, it will be ready when a localisation will be find, it will also display no client until you connect it to QGIS (or another software)
- find the COM port use by Symartic ExtGPS in the tablet settings
- Run QGIS
- connect the GPS to the good COM port
- the cursor will be set to your current position in the QGIS canvas.

Comment: Thank you. I actually did something very similar which I will post below for future users:

I downloaded an app on my android phone called "Bluetooth GPS Output". 
I paired the phone with the tablet via Bluetooth, and opened the application on the mobile phone. I broadcast the signal to the tablet, and went into bluetooth connections and set up the COM port (this was the fix, as the COM port was not set up properly). I then had the option to choose the COM Port (COM Port 5 in this case) to connect to in QGIS. Surprised at the accuracy - usually under 5m in London open spaces using galaxy s6

Comment: Yes I also try this one. But i was not able to make it works with my devices... Only extGPS is working for me