# Live Tracking with Garmin inReach explorer+

Tags: gps, tracking, garmin

I'm trying to connect my Garmin Inreach Explorer+ gps to QGIS (running on a MS Surface 5 tablet) via bluetooth, but have been unsuccessful so far.  The goal is to have to a live tracking tablet while working in the field, passively collecting GPS coords while mapping with QGIS on the tablet.  The GPS pairs and connects to the tablet just fine, however when i try to connect with the live tracking module on qgis, it doesn't work.  Not too sure what else to do...

I have also tried downloading GPSGate, but this also didn't work.  Is it possible to connect a Garmin gps into QGIS for live tracking in the field?

Comment: I expect the COM port is not set correctly see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/243347/bluetooth-my-gps-signal-to-windows-10-tablet-using-qgis

Comment: I bought a Garmin Glo instead, and have connected it successfully to QGIS using the autoconnect feature.  I am now having issues with QGIS tracking and logging my location...for some reason it doesn't follow my movements.  Thanks for your help so far!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from using my Inreach, and some knowledge of the history, the "Garmin" Inreach product line was purchased from DeLorme, and although the device has been rebadged, the software doesn't have many of the standard Garmin formats and interfaces.
I don't think that the Inreach puts a data stream out onto the communication interface. The interface is probably only used for syncing information such as waypoints and contacts, via the Earthmate app. Sorry I can't be more specific.